# I want to ask my boss about my career status

Tags: professionalism, management, job-offer

I would like to ask my boss about my career status through the email..

I start to work with them about 10 days ago and they seems interest in me but they are not giving me any details.. so what should I say to my boss?

Comment: To be honest I work with them through the internet cause they are far from me. I just want to ask them.. how should I write my email?

Comment: you mean I should call my boss on his phone??

Comment: It's common to have some sort of official meeting (appraisal, personnel review) every year, and for those places that have structured salaries, it's part of the yearly raise process. That's the time when you can discuss your current status and goals for the next year.  After 10 days, you don't have a status, nor can your boss make any educated statements about your progress - because you haven't made any yet.

Answer (score 4):

You started your job 10days ago? I think your career status is non-existant - you've done no notably work. Ask after a year, this is the common time to discuss about your career and the projects you've done.

I'm really sorry when I don't get your question correctly. I'm not a native speaker :-)

Comment: I suspect the OP isn't a native english speaker either, as I find his question difficult to understand myself.